# Why do I get this error: Can't resolve './components/forms/LoginForm'

Tags: vue.js, npm

Why do I get this error after running the `npm run dev` command:

```
npm run development

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 5:0-53
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/forms/LoginForm' in 'D:\wamp64\www\my-website\my-website\resources\js'
```

Comment: Well, does the file exist?

Comment: This file exists: LoginForm.vue

Answer (score 1):

Try registering the component like this

```
'./components/forms/LoginForm.vue'
```

Comment: It results in this error: `ERROR in ./resources/js/components/forms/LoginForm.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <script>
|   export default {
|     mixins: [Laraform],

webpack compiled with 1 error`